# OkHttp Caching Policies and ETags

Tags: okhttp

I had some questions about OkHttp and how it chooses to do caching:

1. Does OkHttp honor Weak ETag (which is used by default in Tomcat 7)?  I read somewhere that Chrome ignores any Weak ETags in favor of the `Last-Modified` response header.  I'm not certain if this is true for Chrome, but I wanted to confirm for OkHttp.
2. Does OkHttp prioritize the `ETag` header over the `Last-Modified` header in terms of caching policies?  Or is the `Last-Modified` header prioritized?  Does OkHttp follow a spec to determine this?  Or is it an implementation detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. OkHttp doesn't differentiate between types of ETags. If your server response includes an `ETag` header, it will be used by OkHttp.
2. OkHttp prefers `ETag` over `Last-Modified`. It's an implementation detail.